# Converting text fields to an array and displaying on page with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I am converting a collection of text fields to an array using the following code (assume HTML input fields with values):

```
var bgimgsarray = $("input[class='image_name_input']").map{function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Then I display it on the page using:

```
$("#vardisplay").html("var bgimgs = ["+bgimgsarray+"];");
```

That displays as:

```
var bgimgs=[image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg];
```

However, I need it to display like this:

```
var bgimgs=['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'];
```

Other than informing the user to put ' at the beginning and end of their input, how would I achieve this? I feel like it should be simple but its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the way you are mapping the value.

From

```
return $(this).val();
```

To:

```
return "'"+$(this).val()+"'";
```

Ending code:

```
var bgimgsarray = $("input[class='image_name_input']").map{function(){return "'"+$(this).val()+"'";}).get();
```

You may want to make sure you don't add extra `'`s when the user types them. In that case, make it:

```
return "'"+$(this).val().replace(/^'|'$/g,'')+"'";
```

Comment: Aaah of course, that completely slipped my mind. Thank you very much. And thank you for the little bit of regex, thats very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should already add the quotes when you construct that array. Use the following line to construct you `bgimgsarray` variable:

```
var bgimgsarray = $("input[class='image_name_input']").map{function(){return "'" + $(this).val() + "'";}).get();
```